# Using gstreamer from Raspberry pi to android phone using USB

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I know there's a ton of posts out there about using gstreamer with raspberry pi and android, but I still can't seem to get it right. My pipeline is kind of complicated, but here it is:

Pi Camera -> Pi 1 -> Wireless LAN Radio -> Pi 2 -> USB -> Android Phone

The first part of the pipeline is working, I have tested it streaming to a laptop. Here's the command on Pi 1:

```
raspivid -v -3d sbs -ih -t 0 -h 730 -w 1280 -md 5 -fps 45 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.168.178 port=5000
```

The part that is tripping me up is communicating over USB with the pi and an android phone. I have enabled USB tethering and set the usb0 interface to have a static IP of 192.168.42.42. I'm getting stuck on the semantics of the pipeline and which keywords to use. I've modified the Gstreamer android tutorial 3 so really I just need to know what to put into gst_parse_launch(). I've been trying a command like this on Pi 2:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H264\,\ packetization-mode\=\(string\)1\,\ profile-level-id\=\(string\)640028\,\ sprop-parameter-sets\=\(string\)\"J2QAKKwrQDwBE/LAPEiagA\\\=\\\=\\\,KO4CXLA\\\=\"\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)1748482228\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)1596184480\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)2320 ! fdsink | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! tcpserversink host=192.168.42.42 port=5001 sync=false
```

And this in android:

```
"tcpserversrc host=192.168.42.42 port=5001 ! application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264,packetization-mode=(string)1,profile-level-id=(string)640028,payload=(int)96,ssrc=(uint)1748482228,timestamp-offset=(uint)1596184480,seqnum-offset=(uint)2320 ! rtph264depay ! openh264dec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false"
```

But obviously, these last two are not working.